# Update Redux InitialValues after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am building a form where in some instances form elements are injected from an AJAX call (Duplicate text input for example).

Everything is working great and updating my form however I can't seem to get any *default* values back into the initial form state in my redux store. Below is my custom reducer that keeps track of the form elements. Can I push my new values into the initial state again?

```
//Schema Reducer
case "UPDATE_SCHEMA_FULFILLED":{

        let s = {...state.schema}
        for (let key in action.payload){
            if(s.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                if(key == 'values'){
                    s[key] = {...s[key], ...action.payload[key]}
                }else{
                    s[key] = [...s[key], ...action.payload[key]]
                }

            }
        }

        state = { ...state, 
            loaded: true,
            schema: {...s},
        }
        break;
    }
```

My form is adding the initial values on first load as per the docs:

```
CustomForm = connect(
  state => ({
initialValues: state.schema.schema.values
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    onSubmit: data => dispatch(saveForm(data))
  })
)(CustomForm)
```

This is what is generating the action:

```
import React from 'react'
import { addSchema } from '../actions/schemaActions'

export default class VirtualButton extends React.Component {
constructor(){
    super();
    this.generateNewLayout = this.generateNewLayout.bind(this)
}

generateNewLayout(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.dispatch(addSchema(this.props.owner));
}

render(){

    return <div className="cf__virtual-action"><a href="" onClick={this.generateNewLayout}>Create New</a></div>

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working but I'm not sure if it's performant? Adding the initialize values function to the actions via props:

```
//My button that dispatches the initial call:
this.props.dispatch(addSchema(this.props.owner, this.props.initialize, this.props.initialValues));

export function addSchema($id, initialize, initial){
return function(dispatch) {
    axios.post(config.api+'forms/schema/virtual/'+$id)
    .then((response) => {
        dispatch({type: 'UPDATE_SCHEMA_FULFILLED', payload: response.data})
        initialize({...initial, ...response.data.values});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
}
```